# Linear maps over division rings

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I have read (on Wikipedia, and also on this site) that one can represent linear maps between finite-dimensional modules over division rings by matrices as in the commutative case, but I have never seen the details.

Could anyone tersely explain this very interesting formalism ?

Comment: A whole lot part of linear algebra works fine over division rings: e.g. those modules are free, the basis exchange theorem holds, etc. So, just do the same as in the commutative case but be careful to the order of multiplications of scalars.